# Codeigniter div tag around anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

can we use div tag inside anchor function?

I have this div

```
#first{ opacity:0; }
```

Then I want to put it into my anchor. Here it is:

```
<?php

    if(is_array($databuku)){

        echo '<ol><br>';
        $i = 1;
        foreach($databuku as $key){
            $judul = '<div id="draggable'.$i++.'" class="ui-widget-content"><center><strong>'.$key->tbl_name.'</strong>
                         <br> <br>
                         <a href="hall_a.html">' .$key->index_no. ' / ' .$key->id. '</a>
                         <br>
                         '.anchor('perpustakaan/koreksi_buku/'.$key->id, 'Edit').' |

                         // I want to put the div #first in 'Delete' function below // 
                         '.anchor('perpustakaan/konfirm_hapus_buku/'.$key->id, 'Delete').'

                         </center></div>';
             echo $judul;
        }
        echo '</ol>';
    }

?>
```

I want to put the div #first in anchor -> delete. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 anchor('perpustakaan/konfirm_hapus_buku/'.$key->id, '<div id="first">Delete</div>')
```

Comment: and what if I want to erase the link 'perpustakaan/konfirm_hapus_buku/' --> I want when I click the Delete, then it's only calls to div#first.

Answer (score 0):

As the div opacity is 0 in your `CSS`, so that the div content is not visible to you and if you want to add the div#first in your anchor tag then try,

```
...anchor('perpustakaan/konfirm_hapus_buku/'.$key->id, '<div id="first"></div>Delete')....
```